# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined | Trigger python script from HTML button | Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, referenceerror

I am currently hosting a website on Google App Engine, and the custom.html web-page includes a button that run a python script. My error is clicking that button activates the python script, but my page has the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` and clicking the button throws `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` and a `404 GET` error:

```
send    @   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
goPython    @   custom.html:61
onclick @   custom.html:55
```

[image: ![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is my app.js script where the error is coming from:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){

    $('.slider').slider();
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton();
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip();
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();

    let tooltipInstances;

    window.onload = function() {
      M.FloatingActionButton.init(document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn'));
      tooltipInstances = M.Tooltip.init(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltipped'));

      // You should remove this event listener when it is no longer needed.
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < tooltipInstances.length; ++i) {
          tooltipInstances[i]._positionTooltip();
        }
      });
    }

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

And here is the custom.html page that includes the button:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="../static/js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Content -->

        <button style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 150px" class="search-btn" type="button" value=" Run Script " onclick="goPython()">Do Something
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-vk5WoKIaW/vJyUAd9n/wmopsmNhiy+L2Z+SBxGYnUkunIxVxAv/UtMOhba/xskxh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <script>
            function goPython() {
              $.ajax({
                url: "../Python/main.py",
                context: document.body
              }).done(function() {
                alert('finished python script');;
              });
            }
          </script>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Lastly, while troubleshooting, I removed `<script src="../static/js/app.js"></script>` from custom.html (in case this was causing the jquery issue, which seems to have disappeared but I'm not sure if this was the cause), but I still receive the other same errors under Chrome's developer tools.

[image]

Any advice and insight is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I have mentioned answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-vk5WoKIaW/vJyUAd9n/wmopsmNhiy+L2Z+SBxGYnUkunIxVxAv/UtMOhba/xskxh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And add

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @AyushKatiyar. Just to clarify, do you mean add the script to the top (and don't delete the script where it is now) or move it from where it is now to inside <head>? I just moved it to <head> (and deleted where it currently is) and am getting the same errors as in the last image of my question.

Comment: @Henrik have you moved Jquery script on top od the script for app.js? And can you also verify the relarive palth of app.js.

Comment: @Henrik i have edited my answer  please try using it.

Comment: I've added my file structure to the original post. Are you recommending I add 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

to the very top of app.js as well?

Comment: I have done as your answer suggests (for custom.html), and also added the jquey script to the top of app.js. I am still getting the same errors shown in the second developers tool screenshot in my post, as well as a GET 404 error in jquery.min.js:2 coming from my main.py file (send, ajax, goPython, oneclick).

Comment: The url parameter does not have the path for file. You need to create an api for the task and hit API using ajax . The orevious problem had been solved thats why you are getting  this problem.  If my answer solved your previous problem kindly approve this answer. Kindly create other question related to API creation.

Comment: I'm afraid the previous problem has not been solved, after your suggestion, I am still getting the same errors as shown in the second developer tools screenshot (just above my file structure). 

In your latest comment, are you suggesting that <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> should have a url="" component? Or that the file path in src="" is incorrect?